# Implementation of SVM for classification without library in c++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm studying Support Vector Machine last few weeks. I understand the theoretical concept how I can classify a data into two classes. But its unclear to me how to select support vector and generate separating line to classify new data using C++.

Suppose, I have two training data set for two classes

[image]

After plotting data, I get the following feature space with vector and here, separating line is also clear.

[image]

How to implement this in C++ without library functions. It will help me to clear my implementation concept about SVM. I need to be clear about implementation as I'm going to apply SVM in opinion mining for my native language.

Comment: SVM leds to an optimization problem. You need very strong computational math knowledge to solve it, e.g. quadratic programming optimization

Comment: So, I should go for library?

Comment: Is the restriction of not using existing libraries self imposed, in order to understand how the implementation works?

Comment: @AerofoilKite: you should always go for a library. Altho the question is interesting to better understand how to deal with such problem from the computational point of view

Comment: @MatthiasB, Existing libraries is not helping me to understand implementation of support vector selection. Could you please recommend me any way?

Comment: @dynamic, I know some libraries will do my job. But i want to apply this concept in opinion mining for my native language. I should know the process better to modify the concept.

Comment: If you need to better understand how SVM works, you have to refer to the original paper: http://homepages.rpi.edu/~bennek/class/mmld/papers/svn.pdf

Comment: @AerofoilKite, it should suffice to understand SVMs from theoretical point of view. It's unlikely you'll ever need to modify anything in the SVM source code because all tunable parameters are already "abstracted out" by API. One can give you an algorithm but it alone won't necessary advance your understanding, because of dependence on theory (algorithm is likely to be backed by several theorems). In general, SVM is a linearly-constrained quadratic programming problem, so you need to look for quadratic programming solvers.

Comment: @AerofoilKite, Nevertheless, there is, apparently an ad-hoc method to solve SVM's optimization problem [wiki: SMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization)

Comment: @Barmaley.exe, Can you give me some implementation hints. ? I have already visited that sites. I didn't understand how to implement this.

Comment: @AerofoilKite I haven't implemented SVMs myself (well, I did, but I used quadratic programming library for optimization). If there are specific points you don't understand — ask them here, this is what SO is for. If nothing there makes any sense to you, then the only suggestion I have is to strengthen your knowledge of math first.

Answer (score 1):

I will join to most people's advice and say that you should really consider using a library. SVM algorithm is tricky enough to add the noise if something is not working because of a bug in your implementation. Not even talking about how hard is to make an scalable implementation in both memory size and time.

That said and if you want to explore this just as a learning experience, then SMO is probably your best bet. Here are some resources you could use:

[The Simpliﬁed SMO Algorithm - Stanford material PDF](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/smo.pdf)

[Fast Training of Support Vector Machines - PDF](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68391/smo-book.pdf)

[The implementation of Support Vector Machines using the sequential minimal optimization algorithm - PDF](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~hv/publications/99.04.McGill.thesis.gmak.pdf)

Probably the most practical explanation that I have found is the one on the chapter 6 of the book Machine Learning in action by Peter Harrington. The code itself is on Python but you should be able to port it to C++. I don't think it is the best implementation but it might be good enough to have an idea of what is going on.

The code is freely available:

https://github.com/pbharrin/machinelearninginaction/tree/master/Ch06

Unfortunately there is not sample for that chapter but a lot of local libraries tend to have this book available.

Answer (score 1):

Most cases SVM is trained with SMO algorithm -- a variation of coordinate descent that especially suits the Lagrangian of the problem.
It is a bit complicated, but if a simplified version will be ok for your purposes, I can provide a Python implementation.
Probably, You will be able to translate it to C++

```py
class SVM:
  def __init__(self, kernel='linear', C=10000.0, max_iter=100000, degree=3, gamma=1):
    self.kernel = {'poly'  : lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)**degree,
                   'rbf'   : lambda x,y: np.exp(-gamma*np.sum((y - x[:,np.newaxis])**2, axis=-1)),
                   'linear': lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)}[kernel]
    self.C = C
    self.max_iter = max_iter

  def restrict_to_square(self, t, v0, u):
    t = (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[1]/u[1]
    return (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[0]/u[0]

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.X = X.copy()
    self.y = y * 2 - 1
    self.lambdas = np.zeros_like(self.y, dtype=float)
    self.K = self.kernel(self.X, self.X) * self.y[:,np.newaxis] * self.y
    
    for _ in range(self.max_iter):
      for idxM in range(len(self.lambdas)):
        idxL = np.random.randint(0, len(self.lambdas))
        Q = self.K[[[idxM, idxM], [idxL, idxL]], [[idxM, idxL], [idxM, idxL]]]
        v0 = self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]]
        k0 = 1 - np.sum(self.lambdas * self.K[[idxM, idxL]], axis=1)
        u = np.array([-self.y[idxL], self.y[idxM]])
        t_max = np.dot(k0, u) / (np.dot(np.dot(Q, u), u) + 1E-15)
        self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]] = v0 + u * self.restrict_to_square(t_max, v0, u)
    
    idx, = np.nonzero(self.lambdas > 1E-15)
    self.b = np.sum((1.0 - np.sum(self.K[idx] * self.lambdas, axis=1)) * self.y[idx]) / len(idx)
  
  def decision_function(self, X):
    return np.sum(self.kernel(X, self.X) * self.y * self.lambdas, axis=1) + self.b
```

In simple cases it works not much worth than sklearn.svm.SVC, comparison shown below
[image]

For more elaborate explanation with formulas you may want to refer to [this ResearchGate preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344460740_Yet_more_simple_SMO_algorithm).
Code for generating images can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbeilstein/simplest_smo_ever).